# Where can I rent and fly a kite in Singapore?

Tags: singapore, activities

I am looking for a place in Singapore where I could rent a kite and fly it with my girlfriend. Google returns me a bunch of results, but I am not sure those places are for those who already have kites or they actually have the rental services.

It would be even more awesome, if any place rents LED kites which we could fly in the night!

Comment: @pnuts lol, true, but I am planning tomorrow's plan. Not enough time for me to make my own.

Comment: @pnuts actually, you know what, your suggestion is great! I am now considering making a kite myself! :P

Comment: I did a quick google search to see if it's legal in Singapore.

Comment: @pnuts Eventually we didn't go haha! But now I know there is kite rental service at Marina Barrage!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some details from the [Singapore Kite Association](http://ska.askwing.com/) FAQ:

> Where do SKA members fly their kites?

Sengkang East Way / Sengkang East Rd vacant field next to CHENG LIM (SW 1) LRT

> Where else?

1. West Coat Park CP3
2. Vacant field between Punggol Field and TPE

> Where to buys kites in Singapore?

Readily available at all heartland stores.

> Where to buy materials to make kites?

Try a craft & hobby store : Spotlight

> Does SKA fly luminous kites?

Kites are tethered flying objects. It has come to our attention that a local company is marketing remote control flying crafts (fitted with flashing LED lights) with the word "kite" in their product. These objects are NOT "kites" Conversely, if you see a flying toilet seat tethered on a line, this flying seat is a kite.

For rental see [here](http://www.renttycoons.com/items/view/1038-Kites-for-Rental-or-Want-to-Rent-Kites) (S$12/d)

Answer (score 4):

Another popular place to fly kite is at the **Marina Barrage**, there's a kite shop (http://www.barragecove.com.sg/) at the location but it might be more expensive that what you can get it from other kite shops outside of the Marina area.

There's the one kite seller with a funny name http://www.goflykite.com/ at Chinatown that sort of make use of the [pun in Singlish](http://www.talkingcock.com/html/lexec.php?op=LexLink&lexicon=lexicon&keyword=GO%20FLY%20KITE):

> **GO FLY KITE**  (Contributed by Daniel) Derived from the English
>   admonition "go fly a kite!" which means "piss off", "f*** off", "buzz
>   off", etc, depending on your level of profanity-tolerance. Of course,
>   we economical Singaporeans have removed the extraneous indefinite
>   article. "He know I so busy, still ask me to do things. Ask him go fly
>   kite, lah!"

Other nice places to fly kite includes:

- East/West Coast Park
- Sembawang Park (in the north)
- Jurong Central Park (in the far west)

Almost any other park that near the extremes of Singapore has stronger winds for kite flying (Here's a list of parks: https://www.nparks.gov.sg/gardens-parks-and-nature/parks-and-nature-reserves) ;P

Comment: Note that the Marina Barrage is at the entrance to Marina Bay: there's nothing at all nearby, and it's quite a distance from both the Marina Bay Sands casino/hotel and the "Marina" hotel district.